# Como fazer uma função utilizar quantos argumentos forem fornecidos a ela

Tags: c, argumento

Há alguma forma de fazer uma função utilizar múltiplos argumentos sem a declaração deles? Por exemplo:

```
#import<stdio.h>
#import"rlutil.h" //para as cores

void a(color,string){
    setColor(color);
    printf("%s",string);
    setColor(15); //Seleciona a cor Branca
}
```

Eu queria saber se ha um jeito de colocar

```
a(1,"Este",2,"E",8,"Um",4,"Exemplo");
```

sem declarar `cor1, string1, cor2, string2`, etc.
e que mostrar o resultado

```
Este E Um Exemplo
```

em que **Este** fique azul(1), **E** fique verde(2), **Um** fique em cinza(8) e **Exemplo** fique em vermelho(4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer uma função utilizar quantos argumentos forem fornecidos a ela em C é necessário utilizar "..." na hora de declarar os parâmetros.
No caso do exemplo que você apresentou eu sugiro preservar a função a() como está:

```
void a(color c, string s) {
    setColor(c);
    printf("%s ",s);
    setColor(15); // o número 15 seleciona a cor branca
}
```

E utilizar uma nova função func() que receberia a lista de parâmetros de tamanho variável e chamaria a() a cada par (color,string). Ficaria assim:

```
void func(int num, ...) {  // o inteiro é obrigatório, os três pontinhos 
                           // indicam que a quantidade de parâmetros será
                           // determinada em tempo de execução
    va_list valist; // estrutura que irá receber a lista de argumentos
    va_start(valist, num);  // macro que inicializa a lista de argumentos
    int i, cor;
    char * palavra;

    for ( i= 0; i < num; i=i+2 ) {
        cor = va_arg(valist, int);
        palavra = va_arg(valist, char *);
        a (cor, palavra);
    }

    va_end(valist); // limpa a memória reservada para valist
}
```

No caso deste exemplo sua chamada ficaria assim:

```
func(8, 1,"Este",2,"É",8,"Um",4,"Exemplo");
```

[reference (em inglês)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Pode criar isto:

```
void a(int tamanho, ...) {
    va_list valist;
    va_start(valist, tamanho);
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i += 2) {
        setColor(va_arg(valist, int));
        printf("%s", va_arg(valist, char *));
        setColor(15); //Seleciona a cor Branca
    }
    va_end(valist);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/VarArgs.c).

Não me lembro se é exatamente isto e não posso testar agora, provavelmente tem uns erros, acho que já vi um :), mas a ideia é esta.

[Referência](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=varargs).