# Como receber um numero indeterminado de variáveis em uma função C?

Tags: c, funções

Estou estudando listas em c, e tenho uma função para remover elemento, `Lista* retira(Lista* l, int v)`, como faço para ela receber um numero indeterminado de variavas v para remover? semelhante ao varagars em java.

Comment: Acho que isso resolve seu problema: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120145/101

Comment: @bigown, não sei como poderia usar nessa função.

Comment: A sua pergunta remete exatamente àquilo. Se eu fosse responder aqui, eu responderia aquilo. A pergunta aqui não é específica.

Comment: hmm, decide por não usar.