# Qual significado do operador ( * ) asterisco?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, operadores, parâmetros

Em C este operador é usado em variáveis do tipo ponteiros. Porém, em Python não sei qual a maneira, e qual o motivo para se usar. Porquanto, qual o significado do operador (*) na linguagem Python?

Comment: Este operador serve para multiplicação.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assim como C, esse operador é usado para multiplicação. Ele pode até ser usado para multiplicar uma *string* por um número.

Em C o símbolo também é usado como operador para pegar o valor indicado por um ponteiro e serve também para declarar tipos que sejam ponteiros. Python não tem ponteiros (aparentes), portando nem há alternativa.

Python o usa como sintaxe especial, e não operador, em parâmetro para indicar que aquele parâmetro pode receber uma quantidade indefinida de argumentos. Isso é semelhante ao que o C usa para a função `printf()`, por exemplo ([pode ser visto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120145/101)).

Entenda a [diferença entre parâmetro e argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Note que só pode existir um único parâmetro declarado assim e ele precisa ser o último posicional declarado na função. Parâmetros nominais podem vir em qualquer ordem, inclusive os descritos abaixo.

Existe também o `**` onde pode pegar os nomes dos argumentos (se for passado nominalmente) e com os nomes é possível pegar seus valores já que os nomes são organizados em um dicionário.

Exemplo:

```
def funcao(*parametros):
    for parametro in parametros:
        print(parametro)

def funcao2(**parametros):
    for parametro in parametros:
        print(parametro)

funcao(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
print()
funcao2(a = 2, b = 3)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/jfaBDM). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ieiyzhvl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Multiply.py).

Comment: Ele não precisa ser o último parâmetro declarado, mas o último em uma lista de positional arguments. Aliás, ele pode ser o primeiro parâmetro seguido de vários keyword arguments.

Comment: @PabloPalácios é mesmo? Acho que é a única linguagem que aceita isso, é pedir para dar problema.

Comment: Não é não ;), aliás, te permite sobrescrever assinatura de métodos de maneira segura, sem que o usuário (do seu framework) se confunda com a assinatura sobrescrita e a assinatura original. Exemplos de assinaturas válidas em Python: (*args, **kw), (*args, a=100, **kw), (\*, a=None), etc...

Comment: Eu não vou conseguir achar agora, mas já li os argumentos que outras linguagens usaram para não permitir isso. Mas se funciona assim, ok, está anotado para quem for usar, o crédito é seu.

Comment: Aí você mostra para o Guido, não tenho nada a ver com essa história :p

Comment: Quem negativou poderia informar o que tem de errado.

Comment: Então... já disse ;)

Comment: @PabloPalácios tá bom assim?

Comment: e ainda faltou falar do caso que o "*" aparece isolado na lista de argumentos de uma função - tipo `def foo(a, b, *, c, d): ... ` e tambem do papel dele no caso de assignment de sequências: `a, b, *c, d = range(10)`

Comment: Também vale a pena colocar uns exemplos do uso do asterisco na _chamada_ a funções - que é complementar, mas diferente do seu uso na _declaração_ de funções.

Comment: @jsbueno não falei porque não sei esse uso :D

Comment: Posso completar aí? (Tem uma resposta aceita e com 7 pontos - estranho começar outra - mas - you are the boss)

Comment: @jsbueno você pode fazer o que você quiser :)

Answer (score 9):

## Splat

[Falei disso numa outra questão sobre PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87234/qual-%C3%A9-o-nome-do-operador-usado-no-php-5-6/87242#87242). É um operador que supõe que você passará para o método ou atribuição uma lista de parâmetros.

Por exemplo:

```
def funcao1(a, b=None, c=None):
    print(a, b, c)

>>> funcao1([1, 2, 3])
[1, 2, 3] None None
>>> funcao1(*[1, 2, 3])
1 2 3

def funcao2(*a):
    print(a)

>>> funcao2([1, 2, 3])
([1, 2, 3],)
>>> funcao2(*[1, 2, 3])
(1, 2, 3)
```

Ou ainda:

```
>>> um, dois, *outros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> um
1
>>> dois
2
>>> outros
[3, 4, 5]
```

Nestes casos, como em outras linguagens, o argumento que define um splat deve ser sempre o último numa lista de argumentos de uma função ou numa lista de atribuições.

Comment: Deve ser o último em uma lista de positional arguments.

Answer (score 6):

O asterisco (`*`), em Python, possui várias funcionalidades. A primeira delas, e a mais comum na maioria das linguagens de programação, é realizar a multiplicação entre valores numéricos.

```
resultado = 3 * 2  
print(resultado) # Imprime o valor 6.
```

Além da multiplicação entre números, o asterisco pode ser usado também para multiplicar uma string — semelhantemente ao método de string `repeat()` em algumas linguagens — ou qualquer outro objeto que possua o método especial [`__mul__`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.__mul__) implementado.

```
string = "bola" * 3
lista = [1, 2, 3] * 2
print(string) # Imprime a string "bolabolabola".
print(lista)  # Imprime a lista [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

A segunda função do asterisco é o [desempacotamento de lista de argumentos](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=unpack#unpacking-argument-lists) — como listas, tuplas ou qualquer outro objeto que seja iterável — na chamada de funções, onde cada elemento será passado como argumento para os parâmetros da função.

```
def func(a, b):
    print(a + b)

values = [7, 3, 5]
func(*values) # É o mesmo que fazer func(values[0], values[1], values[2]).
```

A terceira função do asterisco é o inverso da anterior: definir, na assinatura de uma função, que um parâmetro pode receber uma quantidade ilimitada de valores como argumento. Nesse caso, os argumentos serão empacotados em uma tupla e passados para o parâmetro.

```
def func(*values)
    print(values) # Imprime a tupla (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Um detalhe muito importante que devemos ter em mente é que qualquer parâmetro após `*args` será tratado como "*keyword-only*". Isso significa que eles só podem ser usados como "chave-valor", em vez de argumentos posicionais.

```
def func(*args, a, b): pass

func(1, 2, 3, a = 4, b = 5) # Funciona.
func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)         # Não funciona pois é obrigatório nomear A e B.
```

Existe também o operador (`**`), formado por dois asteriscos. Este operador serve para realizar potências e definir na assinatura de uma função que um determinado parâmetro receberá [*keyword arguments*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70886/157404) (tradução: argumentos de palavra chave / argumentos nomeados).

Nesse caso, dentro da função, os valores serão armazenados dentro de um dicionário, e os nomes dos parâmetros que o usuário definiu na chamada da função serão as chaves do mesmo.

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs) # Imprime o dicionário {"name": "Eduardo", "age": 32}

user_age = 2 ** 5 # O resultado disso será 2 elevado a 5 = 32
func(name = "Eduardo", age = user_age)
```

É importante salientar que o parâmetro declarado como *KWARGS* deverá ser sempre o último da função. O motivo disso é que, após a declaração do mesmo, não seria mais possível saber a qual parâmetro um determinado argumento pertence. Por isso, o código abaixo geraria um erro:

```
def func(a, b, **kwargs, c, d): pass
```

Abaixo estão todas maneiras de utilização do `*args` e `**kwargs` na função:

```
def func1(a, b, c, d, *args): pass

def func2(a, b, *args, c, d): pass

def func3(a, b, c, d, **kwargs): pass

def func4(a, b, c, d, *args, **kwargs): pass

def func5(a, b, *args, c, d, **kwargs): pass
```

Além disso, ainda na declaração de funções, é possível utilizar o asterisco para obrigar a nomeação de um ou mais argumentos na chamada da função, sem a necessidade de declarar `*args`.

Para fazer isso, o asterisco deve ser colocado separadamente, e todos os parâmetros nos quais você deseja que sejam "*keyword-only*" devem estar à direita do asterisco.

```
def func(a, b, *, c, d): pass

func(2, 3, c = 10, d = 25) # Funciona.
func(2, 3, 10, 25)         # Não funciona pois é obrigatório nomear C e D.
```

Answer (score -5):

Esse operador é utilizado em multiplicações.

Ex:

```
A = 5
B = 7 
C = A*B
```