# Saída de um código em C com ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro

Preciso entender o que significa cada um dos valores impressos na tela pelo seguinte código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
 int i=5;
 int *p;
 p = &i;
 printf("%u %d %d %d %d \n", p, *p+2,**&p,3**p,**&p+4);
 return 0;
}
```

Pelo que entendi, foi declarado duas variáveis `i` e `p`, porém p foi declarado como um ponteiro (creio que seja isso). Quando ele diz que `p = &i;` significa que agora o valor de `p` é o endereço de `i`. Porém não consegui entender os valores de `*p+2,**&p,3**p,**&p+4.`.

A saída apresenta o seguinte quando executo o código:

```
6487628 7 5 15 9
```

Comment: Tem explicação para todo gosto ;) Assim que é bom no SOpt.

Comment: Sim, agradeço a cada uma das respostas.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[O asterisco é o operador de dereferência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101), ou seja, ele pega o valor que está naquele endereço. Ele só pode ser usado em ponteiros para dar resultados corretos.

`*p` é para pegar o valor do endereço de `p`, portando neste caso o `p` é o endereço de `i` que você já sabe, então ele pega o valor 5 e em seguida soma 2 dando 7.

Em seguida ele faz algo desnecessário, acredito que só para demonstrar o funcionamento. Ele está pegando o endereço de `p` (`&p`), e com ele está pegando o valor deste endereço através do `*` (`*&p`) voltando ter o endereço contido em `p`, portanto volta ter o endereço de `i` que estava em `p`, aí ele novamente pega o valor de `i` (`**&p`). Então tem 3 operadores aí: `* * & p` ou se preferir `(*(*(&p)))`.

O outro leia assim `3 * (*p)`. O início é simples é aritmética básica que já conhece, e o que vem a seguir já aprendeu acima. Ele está pegando o valor que está no endereço de `p` que sabemos que vale 5 (o valor de `i`) e multiplica por 3.

O último é uma mistura do segundo e do terceiro.

Separando as operações para visualizar melhor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    int *p = &i;
    printf("%u\n", p);  //é o endereço de i
    printf("%d\n", *p);  //é o valor de i obtido pelo endereço que está em p
    printf("%d\n", (*p) + 2); //pega o valor de i e soma 2
    printf("%d\n", (&p));  //pega o endereço de p
    printf("%d\n", (*(&p))); //com o endereço de p pega o valor dele, que é o endereço de i
    printf("%d\n", *(*(&p))); //então pega o valor de i, isto é o mesmo que *p
    printf("%d\n", 3 * (*p)); //multiplica 3 pelo valor de i, é o mesmo que 3 * i
    printf("%d\n", *(*(&p)) + 4);  //soma 4 em i através de uma fórmula desnecessária
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xiqM1a). E [no **Coding Ground**](http://tpcg.io/GjkozO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Explain.c).

E se está se perguntando se o `*` tem significado diferente dependo do contexto, sim, tem, ele pode ser usado como multiplicador quando estamos falando de valores normais ou pode ter a forma de acessar o valor de um ponteiro quando estamos acessando um ponteiro. É confuso, não deveria ser assim, mas foi assim que a linguagem foi concebida. O `3**p` demonstra bem isto, o mesmo símbolo está fazendo duas operações completamente distintas.

Answer (score 14):

> a [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247782/64969) tem um viés mais explicativo das operações, essa minha tem um viés de como as operações são feitas, sem maiores detalhamentos

- `p ==> 6487628`: esse é o endereço de `i` na memória
- `*p+2 ==> 7`: a soma de `i` com 2; como `p` aponta para `i`, `*p` pega o valor dentro de `i`
- `**&p ==> 5`: o valor apontado pelo valor apontado pelo endereço de `p`; por pouco, da direita para a esquerda:

  1. `&p` pega o endereço da variável `p`
  2. `*&p` pega a que o endereço de `p` aponta, portanto pega `p`
  3. `**&p`, já sabemos que `*&p ==> p` do passo anterior, portanto isso dá igual a `*p`, que é o valor numérico 5 (`p` aponta para `i`, `i` vale 5)

     - no sentido de ponteiros, endereços e variáveis, `*` e `&` são operações inversas, então elas acabam se anulando; só tem um detalhe, o operador de referência `&` só pode ser aplicado uma vez consecutiva, enquanto que o operador de dereferência `*` pode ser aplicado em cascata consecutivamente
- `3**p ==> 15`: 3 multiplicado pelo valor apontado por `p`; o primeiro `*` é o operador de multiplicação, já o segundo é o de acesso à região de memória
- `**&p+4 ==> 9`: já sabemos que `**&p` é o valor de `i`, então somamos 4, obtendo 9

Answer (score 13):

- `p` aparece como o valor **6487628**. Esse é o valor de fato armazenado em `p`, que é o endereço de `i`.
- `*p+2`, devido à precedência dos operadores, deve ser interpretado como `(*p)+2`. `*p` retorna o valor armazenado no endereço de memória apontado por `p`, que é **5**. Somando, temos o resultado **7**.
- `**&p` é o mesmo que `*p` porque `*` e `&` se cancelam. Um é a operação de criar um ponteiro a partir de uma variável e o outro é a de um valor a partir de um ponteiro. Já vimos que `*p` é **5**.
- `3**p` é interpretado como `3*(*p)`, novamente, devido à precedência dos operadores. Isso é o mesmo que `3*5`, que é **15**.
- `**&p+4` é o mesmo que `*p+4` como visto no outro caso. Isso é interpretado como `(*p)+4`, que é `5+4`, que é igual a **9**

Answer (score 13):

Segue seu código comentado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 5;     /* Atribui 5 ao inteiro 'i' */
    int *p;        /* Declara um ponteiro 'p' para inteiro */
    p = &i;        /* Atribui ao ponteiro 'p' o endereco de 'i' */

    printf("%u\n", p );         /* Endereco armazenado no ponteiro 'p' */
    printf("%d\n", *p + 2 );    /* Soma 2 ao conteudo do inteiro apontado por 'p' */
    printf("%d\n", **&p );      /* Conteudo do inteiro apontado por 'p' (Mesmo que '*p') */
    printf("%d\n", 3 * *p );    /* Multiplica por 3 o conteudo do inteiro apontado por 'p' */
    printf("%d\n", **&p + 4 );  /* Soma 4 ao conteudo do inteiro apontado por 'p' (Mesmo que '*p + 4') */

    return 0;
}
```