# O quê representa o asterisco na definição de uma função em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por exemplo, na documentação do módulo [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html) é comum ver tal notação:

- `pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)`
- `pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=None, *, fix_imports=True)`
- `pickle.load(file, *, fix_imports=True, encoding="ASCII", errors="strict")`
- `pickle.loads(bytes_object, *, fix_imports=True, encoding="ASCII", errors="strict")`

Qual a função deste asterisco nestes casos?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101 não era melhor ter respondido lá?

Comment: @Maniero tenho minhas dúvidas. Acha que caberia?

Comment: A pergunta é idêntica a não ser nas palavras, por que tem alguma dúvida?

Comment: @Maniero de generalizar a pergunta para todos os casos de uso do *. Mas analisando melhor, isso é só um caso específico do que foi comentado lá, então de fato faz sentido.

Comment: Mais geral que "Em C este operador é usado em variáveis do tipo ponteiros, mas em Python não sei qual a maneira, e qual o motivo para se usar, portanto qual o significado do operador (*) na linguagem Python?", beirava o amplo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A resposta que procura existe e se chama PEP. Pepe Legal? Não, PEP 3102.

- [PEP 3102 -- Keyword-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Como o título da PEP já denunciou, esta sintaxe permite definir funções que recebam *apenas* argumentos nomeados, não posicionais. Mas isso é parcialmente verdade. O que acontece é que a função receberá **somente** argumentos nomeados **após** o asterisco. Antes dele os argumentos poderão, ainda, ser posicionais.

Por exemplo, na função `pickle.load` citada você pode receber o argumento `file` de forma posicional, mas qualquer outro argumento deverá ser nomeado.

```
obj = pickle.load('arquivo', encoding='utf-8')  # Ok, um argumento posicional e outros nomeados
obj = pickle.load(file='arquivo', encoding='utf-8')  # Ok, todos os argumentos nomeados
obj = pickle.load('arquivo', 'utf-8')  # Erro, argumento posicional após o asterisco
```

Se o asterisco estiver como primeiro argumento, a função só permitirá argumentos nomeados e se passado qualquer valor posicional um erro `TypeError` será levantado.

```
def soma(*, a, b):
    return a + b
```

A única forma de invocar a função é `soma(a=1, b=2)`. Geralmente esta técnica é utilizada quando a função em questão recebe um (ou mais) argumentos posicionais que são de trivial compreensão e outros argumentos "opções", que determinarão o comportamento da função.

Imagine uma função que compare duas *strings*, podendo ser sensível a caracteres maiúsculos:

```
def comparar(a, b, case_sensitive=False):
    ...
```

Se você chamar `comparar('teste', 'Teste', case_sensitive=True)` fica bem claro o que a função irá fazer, mesmo que nem tenha sido definido o corpo da função. Porém, se chamar a função `comparar('teste', 'Teste', True)` você provavelmente terá que olhar a documentação da função para saber o que o `True` representará.

Antes da PEP ser implementada, era possível fazer algo como:

```
def comparar(a, b, *ignorar, case_sensitive=False):
    ...
```

Mas assim você define um argumento que nem será utilizado, que apenas polui o código, sem considerar que permitiria chamar a função definindo qualquer quantidade de argumentos posicionais, mesmo que fosse utilizado efetivamente dois:

```
comparar('teste', 'Teste', True, True, ['/', '|'], case_sensitive=True)
```

Imagina quanto tempo poderia ser perdido até o leitor perceber que todos esses parâmetros serão ignorados e nem precisariam estar aí?

Você até poderia evitar isso verificando o valor do parâmetro e emitindo uma exceção:

```
def comparar(a, b, *ignorar, case_sensitive=False):
    if ignorar:
        raise TypeError
```

Evitaria a chamada com argumentos desnecessários, mas seria adicionar uma lógica na implementação para valores que nem serão utilizados.

Com isso em mente, definiram a PEP 3102 e, ao omitir o nome do argumento após o asterisco, a mágica acontece.