# O que justificou adicionarem à versão 3.8 do Python a sintaxe para parâmetros somente posicionais?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem

Como consta em [*What’s New In Python 3.8*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html) a [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/), que define a sintaxe para parâmetros somente posicionais, foi implementada.

Conforme a PEP 570 será possível utilizar a barra na definição de parâmetros de uma função para identificar que os parâmetros que antecedem a este caractere serão somente posicionais, em contraste com o asterisco ([PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)), que já era utilizado para definir parâmetros somente nomeados.

- [O quê representa o asterisco na definição de uma função em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/312516/5878)

A partir da versão 3.8 será possível fazer:

```
def foo(a, /, b, *, c):
    ...
```

Em que:

- Parâmetro `a` deverá ser somente posicional;
- Parâmetro `b` poderá ser posicional ou nomeado;
- Parâmetro `c` deverá ser somente nomeado;

Ou seja, as únicas formas possíveis de se chamar a função seriam `foo(1, 2, c=3)`, com `b` posicional, ou `foo(1, b=2, c=3)`, com `b` nomeado. Qualquer outra variação que tenha `a` nomeado ou `c` posicional resultará em erro.

Dado que uma função, por padrão, já aceita parâmetros posicionais, qual foi a motivação para ser definido uma forma de obrigar que sejam posicionais?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que a maior motivação é espelhar do lado do Python o que já é possível fazer a bastante tempo quando se escreve uma função em C, para ser usada no Python. Por exemplo, funções como `print`, apesar de ter o primeiro parâmetro documentado como `value` em que esse primeiro parâmetro não pode ser passado como Named Argument - ele é obrigatoriamente posicional.

Dessa forma, até o Python 3.7, você tem mais flexibilidade para declarar parâmetros em funções escritas em C do que em funções escritas em Python - essa nova sintaxe deixa o lado do Python equivalente.

Há mais coisas utlidades que podem ser achadas nas listas de discussão python-ideas e python-dev - mas não vou me lembrar agora. Se fosse algo realmente com muitos casos de uso, e que desse pra fazer um monte de coisas novas, essa sintaxe já teria sido incluida antes - me lembro de ver gente pedindo por ela há vários anos já.

A maior comodidade é realmente ter funções em que os primerios parâmetros sejam tão óbvios que tem que ser os primeiros, que não faça a ordem deles poder ser trocada. (Outra que me verio a cabeça foi o `open`, mas no `open` o nome do arquivo pode ser passado fora de ordem - talvez justamente por que essa sintaxe não existia ainda).

Além da minha resposta informal, como a sintaxe tem uma PEP aprovada, toda PEP tem uma sessão entitulada "Motivation" - lá consta a motivação formal e pode esclarecer melhor essa questão e ter mais exemplos de uso - 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#motivation

Acho que está bem explicado lá - e eles resumem os benefícions mais objetivos em 3 casos de uso:

- "Quando uma função pode aceitar qualquer parâmetro com nome, mas também pode aceitar um parâmetro posicional" - é  o caso da chamada `dict` para criar dicionários: o primeiro parâmetro anônimo pode ser outro dicionário ou um iterável com chaves/valores, mas os parâmetros com nome constroem um dicionário com os nomes dos parãmetros passados. Se o primeiro parâmetro tivesse um nome (ex. "intial" ou "values"), esse nome não poderia nunca ser usado como parâmetro para criar uma chave em uma chamada do tipo `a = dict(name="Joao", values=[10,12])`.
- "Quando um parâmetro não tem nenhum significado semântico externo": isso é, o nome só vai ser importante dentro da função chamada, como em funções que aceitam um único argumento - e o usuário daquela função não tem que se preocupar em como isso está implementado, simplesmente passar qualquer objeto como parâmetro.
- "Quando os parâmetros de uma API sejam requeridos e não tenham ambiguidade" (esse é o caso das funções "print" e "open" que mencionei)