# Para que serve o asterisco como "parâmetro" nas funções em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, funções, parâmetros

Eu estava dando uma lida na documentação da versão 3.8 do Python, na parte da nova sintaxe para parâmetros posicionais, e encontrei a seguinte função:

```
def f(a, b, /, c, d, *, e, f):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Na função acima, os parâmetros `a` e `b` são apenas posicionais. Já os outros quatro podem ser utilizados como palavras-chave.

```
f(1, 2, 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6)
```

Mas notem que entre os parâmetros, existe um asterisco solto — sem parâmetro. A minha dúvida é: o que é esse asterisco? Para que ele serve?

Comment: @Maniero acho que a pergunta é a respeito do "bare asterisk" que fiz que todos os parametros após o `*` precisam parametros nomeados, as perguntas que voce colocou para fechar a pergunta nao me parecem responder isso porque elas falam apenas de args e kwargs quando na verdade a duvida se refere ao `*` como um parametro "solto".

Jean, em resumo o asterisco serve como delimitador, todos os parâmetros depois dele precisam ser nomeados, e os parametros antes dele nao sao nomeados.

Comment: @RFL A segunda pergunta indicada eu acho que responde, pois [a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/312517/112052) diz: "*a função receberá somente argumentos nomeados após o asterisco. Antes dele os argumentos poderão, ainda, ser posicionais*" etc...

Comment: @hkotsubo De fato responde. Eu não tinha visto ela quando pesquisei no site.

Comment: @RFL Obrigado pela ajuda. Só tenho uma dúvida agora... como assim você "fez"? Está dizendo que foi você que criou essa sintaxe para a linguagem oficialmente? '-'

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 foi erro de digitação, eu quis dizer "que DIZ que todos..."