# Há alguma forma de passar os parâmetros para uma função de forma constante?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parâmetros

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte, tenho essa conexão do InfluxDB:

```
InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')
```

Porém quero transformar esses parâmetros em uma constante, para não ter que ficar alterando no código toda vez que mudar.

No inicio pensei em criar para cada parâmetro:

```
INFLUXDB_HOST = 'influxdb'
INFLUXDB_PORT = 8086
INFLUXDB_USERNAME = 'root'
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD = 'root'
INFLUXDB_DATABASE = 'example'
```

Mas será que tem uma forma de juntar todos essas variáveis dentro de uma e passar direto na função?

```
InfluxDBClient(MINHAS_VARIAVEIS)
```

*Influx* não é o problema em si, o mesmo caso seria para o exemplo abaixo.

```
In [1]: def conta(a, b, c):
   ...:     print(a,b,c)
   ...:     

In [2]: conta(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)

In [3]: teste = (1,2,3)

In [4]: conta(teste)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5feac543a26b> in <module>()
----> 1 conta(teste)

TypeError: conta() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

In [5]:
```

No caso eu não mudaria dentro da função (pois no Influx não há como).

Comment: A função `InfluxDBClient` é sua? Pode alterar?

Comment: Não, a unica restrição e nao mudar a função, senão eu faria uma tupla ou lista.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você poderia declarar suas varáveis numa lista, e então usar `*` para passar cada item como um argumento

```
CONFIG = ('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')
InfluxDBClient(*CONFIG)
```

Você poderia criar uma função que chama a InfluxDBClient passando os parâmetros necessarios

```
def localhostConnect(): return InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')
```

Comment: Não sabia que existia esse * no python

Answer (score 6):

Tem algumas formas, mas não parece ser bem o que deseja. Estou partindo do pressuposto que pode e aceita mudar a função para trabalhar com parâmetro diferente do que aceita atualmente, nem que seja outra função. Se não pode fazer isto não o que fazer, terá que escrever todas variáveis, o que não é o fim do mundo. Suas opções são:

- Receber uma lista (ou dicionário, ou tupla) com esses valores. Em vez de ter variáveis soltas você teria uma lista. Isto pode correr de duas formas:

  - Receber normalmente como um parâmetro
  - Receber como uma lista de parâmetros usando o `*` ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101))
- Deixar de ter parâmetro e aí tem duas opções:

  - Deixar as variáveis como globais (em geral não recomendado, mas há casos úteis), que podem ser acessadas então de qualquer lugar e já pega os dados lá dentro
  - Cria uma função que retorna esses valores em uma lista ou dicionário ou tupla, então sempre que mudar o valor tem que mudar nesta função, e dentro da sua função consumidora você chama esta função e pega os dados. Assim fica um pouco mais organizado e só a função fica global e não as variáveis.

O que dá para fazer se não pode mudar a função é criar abstração, o que eu sempre falo, você chama a função que deseja do jeito que deseja dentro de uma função, e aí sempre chama esta função mais simples. Abstração é uma arte perdida que programadores antigos sempre usaram facilmente para esconder complexidade. Aí veio a orientação a objeto e as pessoas pararam de pensar nisso, só sabem agora criar soluções complexas.

Não tendo acesso à função original pode fazer isso em uma outra onde acessa as variáveis globais (que é o que parece querer) diretamente ali, assim não tem mais que digitar nada extra se a preocupação é esta. Exemplo:

```
def dbConnect(): return InfluxDBClient(INFLUXDB_HOST, INFLUXDB_PORT, INFLUXDB_USERNAME, INFLUXDB_PASSWORD = 'root', INFLUXDB_DATABASE)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/IO/Connection.py).

Answer (score 1):

você pode encapsular sua função

```
 def novoNome(ParametroMutavel):
    return oldFunction(Parametrofixo, ParametroMutavel)
```

---

Exemplo com seu código

```
def newFunction():
    return InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', 'example')
```

Suponhamos que o exemple sempre mude

```
def newFunction(parametroMutavel):
    return InfluxDBClient('localhost', 8086, 'root', 'root', parametroMutavel)
```

suponhamos que tenha muitos parametros mutáveis voce pode passar por dicionário

```
obj = {
    'ip':'localhost',
    'port':8086,
    'user':'root',
    'pw':'root',
    'ex':'example',
}
def newFunction(dicionario):
    return InfluxDBClient(dicionario.get('ip'), dicionario.get('port'), dicionario.get('user'), dicionario.get('pw'), dicionario.get('ex'))
```