# Remover caracteres indesejados de uma List<string> sem percorrer a lista

Tags: c#, .net, string, lista

Seja o seguinte trecho uma aplicação Windows Forms.

```
List<string> lista_strings = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    lista_strings.Add("TST1234"); //preenchendo a lista
}

for (int i = 0; i < lista_strings.Count; i++)
{
    lista_strings[i] = lista_strings[i].Substring(3); //retirando os caracteres
                                                      //iniciais de cada posição
}
```

Criei um laço `for` para que, de posição em posição, eu possa retirar os caracteres iniciais de cada `string`("TST") dentro da lista de strings `lista_strings`. Existe uma forma de **retirar os caracteres iniciais de toda lista** sem precisar alterar seus valores um por vez?

Comment: Não me parece muito claro o que deseja. A descrição está um pouco confusa.  Tem algo errado no seu código? Tem algo mais que deseja fazer? Tem alguma melhoria desejada?

Comment: Em minha aplicação eu tenho sempre novos elementos na lista de strings por isso acho que não compensa percorrer toda a lista. Sempre tem três caracteres iniciais em todas strings e concatenado o número que eu quero. Desejo retirá-los para depois converter para int. Esse é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Isso eu entendi, tá bem claro, mas o que você quer que a gente responda?

Comment: Como remover os caracteres de maneira mais simples, sem ficar percorrendo toda a lista, ja que tenho certeza que os caracteres estarão presentes em todas as strings.

Comment: Se você quer remover em toda a lista como acha que é possível fazer isto sem percorrer toda lista? Impossível.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podemos utilizar o *Linq* para efetuarmos a alteração da `string` de forma mais simples, pois pelo que entendi você deseja remover o laço `for`.

Segue abaixo o exemplo com o *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

lista_strings = lista_strings.Select(s => s.Length > 3 ? s.Substring(3) : s).ToList();
```

Aqui nessa iteração estamos pegando cada string da nossa lista, que está sendo representada pelo `s` no `Select()`, após isso verificamos se o tamanho dessa `string` é maior que 3 para evitarmos lançar `Exception` caso não possua a quantidade de caracteres necessária, caso possua mais que 3 caracteres iremos realizar o `Substring(3)` (conforme você já fazia), caso contrário pegamos o conteúdo da forma que ele está atualmente.

Answer (score 7):

> Existe uma forma de retirar os caracteres iniciais de toda lista sem precisar alterar seus valores um por vez?

Não, não existe. A própria definição do problema já indica isso. Se você quer passar por todos os elementos da lista para alterar seu conteúdo o único jeito é passar por todos os elementos.

Se a pergunta fosse sem usar um laço eu poderia dizer que depende. É virtualmente impossível fazer sem um laço, de uma forma ou de outra. A única forma é fazer manualmente cada elemento, o que é uma maluquice.

Aí você deve estar dizendo, mas a outra resposta mostrou que dá para fazer. Mas na verdade não dá. Dá para esconder o laço, como você pode fazer em uma função qualquer, como dá para fazer sempre que criar uma [abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360556/101). A questão é que o .NET já tem uma abstração pronta chamada [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101).

O que o LINQ faz é percorrer objetos enumeráveis, como é o caso da lista. Como ele percorre uma lista? Através de um laço. Não tem mágica, só que ela está dentro de um método.

Então é sempre melhor usar LINQ? Não. Depende do que quer fazer. Se deseja manipular o dado de forma mais complexa o LINQ pode não ser uma boa. Se precisa de performance o LINQ não te atende bem, ele tem um custo consideravelmente maior quando isto é importante. Faça o teste com ambos.

Mas o custo é só este? Não, ele cria uma lista nova, faz nova alocação e é ineficiente e pode provocar pausas indesejadas na aplicação com mais frequência.

Claro, tudo isso depende de uma série de fatores, mas se você usar indiscriminadamente sem saber como cada abstração funciona vai se envolvendo em problemas, por isso é preciso entender tudo e tomar as decisões mais adequadas. Não pode ser a escolha do mais bonitinho.

Ele é muito mais curto e óbvio? Não, só um pouco, veja a diferença:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++) if (s.Length > 3) lista[i] = lista[i].Substring(3);
lista = lista.Select(s => s.Length > 3 ? s.Substring(3) : s).ToList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Substring.cs).