# Por que existe tanta diferença de performance entre stream e loops normais?

Tags: java, loop, desempenho, stream

Estava lendo um [artigo](https://medium.com/@milan.mimica/slow-like-a-stream-fast-like-a-loop-524f70391182) relacionado à performance das *streams*/*loops*, e me assustei com a diferença de performance entre a utilização de *loops* em relação à grandes quantidades de dados.

Resolvi realizar um teste rápido utilizando o seguinte código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int limite = 10_000;
    
    long inicioFor = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    
    long terminoFor = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    long inicioStream = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    IntStream.range(0, limite).forEach(System.out::println);
    
    long terminoStream = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Usando for: " + (terminoFor - inicioFor) );
    System.out.println("Usando stream: " + (terminoStream - inicioStream) );
}
```

É um código relativamente simples, porém notei uma coisa interessante:

1. Quando o `limite` é definido com valor `10_000`, o tempo resultante é o seguinte:

> Usando for: 54
> Usando stream: 72

2. Quando o `limite` é definido com valor `1_000_000`, a *stream* é relativamente mais rápida:

> Usando for: 4314
> Usando stream: 4202

Entendo que este é um teste simples, sem utilização de ferramentas de *benchmark* entre outras métricas.

Gostaria de saber o porquê da existência desta diferença de tempo no processamento utilizando *streams* e *loops*, posso não estar correto, mas parece que as *streams* *performam* melhor quanto maior a quantidade de dados (caminhando para a questão das streams *infinitas*).

---

Complementando com algumas informações colocadas pelo @Victor, tive resultados extremamente diferentes retirando as operações de IO:

1. Quando o `limite` é definido com valor `10_000`:

> Usando for: 0
> Usando stream: 36

2. Quando o `limite` é definido com valor `1_000_000`:

> Usando for: 2
> Usando stream: 43

Conforme apontado também por @Maniero, a razão se deve ser o alto custo para fazer a infraestrutura funcionar de acordo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Acabei de responder sobre isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361940/101) (O LINQ é o *stream* do C#, grosso modo). O *stream* é uma abstração, é uma camada a mais para executar, há um custo para fazer esta infraestrutura funcionar, há chamadas de função onde não deveria ocorrer no puro, há [indireções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), tudo isso tem custo, então ele precisa ser mais caro que a execução pura e simples de um laço. Está executando mais coisas, tem que ser mais lento.

O *stream* é um método que tem um laço dentro dele e que executa um método dentro dele de forma indireta, neste exemplo é o `System.out::println`. Que por sinal não é uma boa forma porque ele é IO e o custo disso é tão alto que você está medindo algo como 98% do tempo o IO e não o mecanismo do laço ou do *stream*. Em algo que custa pouco a diferença é muito maior.

Até me impressiona a excelente otimização que o compilador Java faz, mas o teste onde dá o `for` mais lento certamente pegou alguma interferência, não tem como ele ser mais lento. Certamente em grande volume o custo da infraestrutura pode não impactar tanto, mas não pode ser mais rápido. E por isso que dá uma discrepância entre o seu resultado e do Victor, o dele executa muitas vezes que diminui a influência da infra do *stream*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Há algo mais bizarro acontecendo. Mesmo fazendo o bechmark sem colocar o System.out dentro do loop ou do Stream, ainda assim o resultado é estranho.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Tem o código? Eu posso tentar explicar o motivo se vê-lo. Não é só a indireção da chamada que causa a lentidão.

Comment: `var x = new int[1];`, `IntStream.range(0, limite).forEach(z -> x[0] = z);`, `x[0] = i;`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa este exemplo é melhor porque tira o IO que é lento. Qual é a proporção que eencontrou?

Comment: Postei uma resposta.

Comment: Vou ver, mas não entendi o que achou de mais bizarro.

Comment: Era um erro meu enquanto estava codificando.

Answer (score 10):

Bem, fiz esse teste:

```
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var limite = 50_000_000_000L;
        var x = new long[1];

        var inicioStream1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LongStream.range(0, limite).forEach(z -> x[0] = z);
        var terminoStream1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        var inicioFor1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (var i = 0L; i < limite; i++) {
            x[0] = i;
        }
        var terminoFor1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        var inicioStream2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LongStream.range(0, limite).forEach(z -> x[0] = z);
        var terminoStream2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        var inicioFor2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (var i = 0L; i < limite; i++) {
            x[0] = i;
        }
        var terminoFor2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Usando for: " + (terminoFor1 - inicioFor1));
        System.out.println("Usando stream: " + (terminoStream1 - inicioStream1));
        System.out.println("Usando for outra vez: " + (terminoFor2 - inicioFor2));
        System.out.println("Usando stream outra vez: " + (terminoStream2 - inicioStream2));
    }
}
```

O resultado foi esse:

```
Usando for: 15169
Usando stream: 18422
Usando for outra vez: 15140
Usando stream outra vez: 18498
```

Quando você for fazer um bechmark de alguma coisa, lembre-se que o IO para o console é uma operação custosa. Isso significa que você nunca deve usar `System.out.println` ou `System.out::println` dentro do código que você está avaliando, porque ele vai interferir bastante com a performance daquilo que você está avaliando.

Acreditar que o `System.out.println` tem um custo de desempenho zero ou desprezível é um erro comum.

Comment: De fato o IO estava afetando o resultado, testando o mesmo exemplo retirando a operação de IO ficou claro até no meu exemplo que a stream é realmente mais lenta :)

Comment: Foi só 20% de diferença na performance? Eu esperava algo mais gritante