# Método Fibonacci recursivo muito lento, qual a causa?

Tags: java, loop, recursão

Fiz um programa com recursividade, porém quando o usuário digita `50`, o processamento para gerar a sequência Fibonacci já passa ficar **extremamente** lento.

Será que é devido ao processamento de entrada/saída de dados no console? Existe um modo que seja mais rápido em Java, sem ser `Scanner`, `BuffererReader` ou `OutputStream`?

**CÓDIGO:** 
***subclasse:***

```
package Fib;

public class Fibonacci {
    public int calculaFibonacci(int n) {  
           if (n == 0)  
              return 0;  
           if (n == 1)  
              return 1;  
           return calculaFibonacci(n-1) + calculaFibonacci(n-2);  
    }
}
```

***ClassePrincipal***:

```
package TesteFibo;

import java.util.Scanner;

import Fib.Fibonacci;

public class chamaFibo {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter one number integer:");
        int tes = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();


        Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci();
        int i = fibo.calculaFibonacci(tes);
        //System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println("Fibonacci number: ");
        System.out.println(i);


        sc.close();
        }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Troque a imagem pelo código por favor

Comment: Como o @VirgilioNovic disse, coloque o código na pergunta e não um print da sua tela. Existe a opção de editar a pergunta e inserir o código.

Comment: Sim, desculpem. Já postei :) Obrigada.

Comment: O problema não é a saída de dados, e sim a própria recursão: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710949 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/49052327

Comment: Hmmmm ... Vou mudar a recursividade e testar, kkk obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme explicado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710949), o problema é a recursão em si, e não a entrada e saída dos dados (até porque você só usa o `Scanner` e o `println` poucas vezes e fora da função recursiva, então eles não são a causa da lentidão). Inclusive, segue uma tradução/adaptação da explicação que tem [lá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710949):

> Se `F` for a sua função recursiva, chamar `F(10)` faz o seguinte:
>
> ```
>  F(10) = F(9)                           +   F(8)
>  F(10) = F(8)          +   F(7)         +   F(7)          +  F(6)
>  F(10) = F(7) + F(6)   +   F(6) + F(5)  +   F(6) + F(5)   +  F(5) + F(4)
>  ....
> ```
>
> Repare que `F(8)` é calculada duas vezes, `F(7)` 3 vezes, e assim por diante. Quanto maior o número inicial, mais chamadas recursivas - e neste caso, redundantes - serão feitas, e isso [cresce exponencialmente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360773) conforme o valor inicial.

Sem contar que todas essas chamadas ficam "penduradas", esperando o retorno das chamadas recursivas abaixo delas, até que se chegue em `F(1)` e `F(0)` (que é quando a função para de fazer novas chamadas recursivas e retorna um valor). Dependendo do valor inicial e da [configuração da sua JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700459), isso pode estourar o *stack*, [gerando um `StackOverflowError`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18368406).

---

Modifiquei suas funções para termos uma ideia do que acontece.

Criei um contador para vermos quantas chamadas são feitas para a função, e mudei os tipos de `int` para `long`, já que os resultados estavam estourando o [valor máximo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) que um `int` suporta (que é [cerca de 2 bilhões](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE)):

```
public class Fib {

    static long CONTADOR;

    public static long calculaFibonacci(long n) {
        CONTADOR++;
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        return calculaFibonacci(n - 1) + calculaFibonacci(n - 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CONTADOR = 0;
        calculaFibonacci(50);
        System.out.println(CONTADOR);
    }
}
```

O resultado foi:

> 40730022147

Ou seja, mais de 40 **bilhões** de chamadas recursivas. Não é à toa que ficou lento.

Se calcularmos para 25, o resultado é:

> 242785

Ou seja, dobrando o número inicial (de 25 para 50), a quantidade de chamadas recursivas aumenta de 242 mil para mais 40 bilhões (de fato um aumento exponencial, como já explicado).

---

Por que não fazer sem recursão? Independente do número inicial, é apenas uma chamada de função com um *loop* simples. Esta é a solução que eu usaria (a menos que você esteja estudando recursão, claro).

```
public long fib(long n) {
    long a = 0;
    long b = 1;
    long c = 1;
    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

A complexidade deste algoritmo cresce linearmente - e não mais exponencialmente - de acordo com o valor inicial, sem contar que [métodos iterativos são bem menos custosos se comparados aos recursivos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/478570).

---

#### Observações

- Se quiser, também é possível usar a recursão, porém guardando os resultados já computados (evitando assim que sejam recalculados), usando técnicas de [*memoization*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822556) - o que já diminui bastante a quantidade de chamadas.
- Isso não quer dizer que `println` nunca causará problemas de desempenho. Na verdade, se você usá-lo dentro da função recursiva (para imprimir os valores intermediários, por exemplo), isso [vai deixá-la mais lenta também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361973/112052). Mas **neste caso específico**, como o I/O é feito somente fora da função, não é a causa da lentidão.