# Imprimir maior número de um array

Tags: java

Tenho um programa onde leio 3 valores e armazeno em um array, porém gostaria de imprimir o maior valor desse array.

Segue abaixo o meu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] grade = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Insert your grade: ");
        grade[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(grade[0]);
}
```

Comment: Olha esse esse exemplo: `[2,5,7]; (5-2=3),(7-2=5)` Conclusão: Toda diferença que é positivo é maior,se for negativa é menor,e se for 0 é igual. Formula : Valor selecionado - valor inicial.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma maneira de encontrar o maior número é simplesmente percorrer o array e ir comparando os seus valores:

```
int maior = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int indiceMaior = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
    if (grade[i] > maior) {
        maior = grade[i];
        indiceMaior = i;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Maior número é %d, no índice %d", maior, indiceMaior);
```

O `maior` começa com [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE), que é o menor valor que um inteiro pode ter em Java (no caso, é [`-2147483648`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE)). Eu começo com o menor valor possível, pois assim garanto que, não importa quais números eu tenha no array, todos serão maiores ou iguais a ele.

Em seguida faço o loop, e para cada elemento do array, eu vejo se ele é maior do que `maior`. Isso quer dizer que, durante o *loop*, a variável `maior` contém "o maior número que encontrei até agora". Quando eu encontro um número maior, eu atualizo o valor de `maior`, e também o seu respectivo índice (já que você informou [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401190/imprimir-maior-numero-de-um-array-java#comment787422_401196) que queria o índice).

Repare que no loop eu uso `grade.length` em vez de colocar o número `3` explicitamente. Assim, se o tamanho do array mudar, você não precisa atualizar o seu `for`.

Ao final do loop, é só imprimir os valores.

---

#### Detalhes

Se o maior número aparecer mais de uma vez no array, o índice será o do primeiro deles. Por exemplo, se o array for:

```
int[] grade = { 2, 1, 2 };
```

Nesse caso, a saída será:

```
Maior número é 2, no índice 0
```

Ou seja, o primeiro `2` será considerado o maior (o que está na terceira posição - no índice 2 - será desconsiderado).

---

Tem ainda um [*egde case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case), que é quando o array está assim:

```
int[] grade = { Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
```

Neste caso a saída é:

```
Maior número é -2147483648, no índice -1
```

Como o programa não entra nenhuma vez no `if` (já que nenhum dos valores é maior que `Integer.MIN_VALUE`), o índice acaba sendo `-1`.

Isso daria para resolver de dois jeitos. O primeiro é mudando a condição do `if` para `>=`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
    if (grade[i] >= maior) {
        maior = grade[i];
        indiceMaior = i;
    }
}
```

Só que agora, quando há valores repetidos, ele considera a última ocorrência. Portanto, a saída é:

```
Maior número é -2147483648, no índice 2
```

E no exemplo anterior, que o array é `{ 2, 1, 2 }`, ele também passaria a retornar o índice 2.

Outra maneira de resolver seria começar com o primeiro elemento (em vez de `Integer.MIN_VALUE`), e percorrer o array a partir da segunda posição:

```
int[] grade = { Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
int maior = grade[0];
int indiceMaior = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < grade.length; i++) {
    if (grade[i] > maior) {
        maior = grade[i];
        indiceMaior = i;
    }
}
```

Agora a saída é:

```
Maior número é -2147483648, no índice 0
```

---

#### Bônus

Se você só quiser encontrar o maior número do array, **sem se importar com o índice**, há outras alternativas (embora eu entenda que *provavelmente* é um exercício e que o professor queira que seja feito em um loop, mas enfim).

A partir do Java 8, é possível usar a API de *streams*:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

int maior = Arrays.stream(grade).max().getAsInt();
```

Claro que isso no fundo é um loop disfarçado (além de ter um [desempenho pior que um loop simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052)), mas é uma alternativa.

---

Outro jeito seria usar um [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) em vez de um array, assim é possível usar o método [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-):

```
List<Integer> notas = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println("Insert your grade: ");
    notas.add(input.nextInt());
}
int maior = Collections.max(notas);
```

---

Por fim, **para o caso específico em que o array possui somente 3 valores**, nem precisa de loop. Basta usar [`Math.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) duas vezes:

```
int maior = Math.max(Math.max(grade[0], grade[1]), grade[2]);
```

Comment: O java tem o método apply no math.max?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper Não

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Apenas faça uma verificação usando o `for` desta seguinte forma:

```
int valorMaximo = grade[0];

for(int number:grade){
    if (valorMaximo < number){
        valorMaximo = number;
    }
}
```

Para verificar em qual índice está o maior número basta acrescentar uma variável auxiliar para guardar a posição do valor no `for`. Para ficar mais simples, você pode até substituir o for `each` por um for normal. Veja como ficaria:

```
int valorMaximo = grade[0];
int index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){
    if (grade[i] > valorMaximo){
        valorMaximo = grade[i];
        index = i;
    }
}
```

Esse código funciona também para números negativos. Veja bem, entre o número `-4` e `-1` qual é o maior deles para você ? Quando o programa passar pela verificação do for, ele irá obter sempre o valor que seja maior do que o que ele possui. 
Logo se o array for um `{-3,5,-1}`, o maior valor que você obterá seja o `5`, pois na primeira vez a variável terá o valor `-3`, mas logo no próximo loop ele terá o valor `5` pois o número `5` é maior que o número `-3`. Depois disso ele irá para mais um loop, porém não obterá o valor `-1` pois o número `-1` é menor que o valor que a variável possui.

Depois dessa verificação é só imprimir o valor final. Espero ter lhe ajudado :)

Comment: Muito obrigado, fiz oque comentou e funcionou!

Comment: @PedroGuilherme Faltou testar quando o array só tem números negativos...

Comment: Verdade, gostaria de saber tambem como eu informo qual o indice que o maior valor esta, teriam como me ajudar nisso ??

Comment: sim, eu vou editar a minha resposta ok ?

Comment: Funcionou aqui, muito obrigado novamente!!