# Preencher uma matriz e somar seus números

Tags: java, matriz

Eu preciso fazer um programa (MATRIZ) que realize a soma de todos os elementos de uma matriz 10x10, contendo números inteiros.

Mas eu não estou conseguindo somar e nem colocar valores em todos os elementos da matriz.

Como eu não uso muito matriz eu não entendo muito bem o funcionamento.
Meu código:

```
public class Exercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int matriz [][] = new int [10] [10];
        int linha;
        int coluna;
        int resultado;

        for (linha = 0; linha >=10; linha++)
        {
            for (coluna = 0; coluna >= 10; coluna++)
            {
            }
        }
        //Não consegui colocar valores nas posições da linha e nem da coluna 

        resultado = matriz [linha] + matriz[coluna];
        System.out.println (resultado);

    }

}
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Sei que em muitos fóruns é comum fazer isso, mas aqui não precisa. Vc já aceitou a resposta abaixo e isso é o suficiente para que os demais saibam que o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu laço está incorreto, você começa em 0 e vai até a linha estar menor que o tamanho da matriz, o mesmo se repete com a coluna:

```
for( int linha = 0; linha < matriz.length; linha++) {
    for( int coluna = 0; coluna < matriz[linha].length; coluna++) {
    }
}
```

Sua linha de soma dos resultados deveria estar dentro do laço, sendo que ela não deve somar as posições, deve somente pegar o valor e somar ao seu resultado:

```
resultado += matriz [linha][coluna];
```

Podendo ser também da seguinte forma:

```
resultado = resultado + matriz[linha][coluna];
```

---

Efetuando as correções em seu código, ele ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
public class Exercicio {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matriz[][] = new int[10][10];
    int soma = 0;

    //Laço responsável por preencher a matriz com números quaisquer
    for( int linha = 0; linha < matriz.length; linha++) {
      for( int coluna = 0; coluna < matriz[linha].length; coluna++) {
        //Gera um numero qualquer para a matriz
        matriz[linha][coluna] = linha * coluna;
      }
    }

    //Laço responsável por efetuar a soma de todos os valores presentes na matriz
    for( int linha = 0; linha < matriz.length; linha++) {
      for( int coluna = 0; coluna < matriz[linha].length; coluna++) {
        soma += matriz[linha][coluna];
      }
    }

    System.out.println(soma);
  }
}
```

Veja que fiz um laço somente para gerar valores, você pode gerar os valores de diversas formas, esse é apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, como havia falado não mexo muito com matrizes, aparentemente foi um erro básico, não sabia que a soma estava sendo realizada de forma errada ;-;,

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa para somar os valores da matriz é usar o [*enhanced for*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) (que alguns chamam de "foreach"):

```
int matriz[][] = new int[10][10];
...
// assumindo que a matriz já está com os valores preenchidos
int soma = 0;
for (int[] linha : matriz) {
    for (int valor : linha) {
        soma += valor;
    }
}
```

Não existem matrizes de fato em Java, e para simulá-las podemos usar arrays de arrays. Então `matriz` é na verdade um array, e cada elemento dela é outro array (e [nada impede que as "linhas" da "matriz" tenham tamanhos diferentes](https://ideone.com/ieAT3d)).

Por isso no primeiro `for` eu declaro `int[] linha`, pois cada elemento da matriz é um array de `int` (um `int[]`). Em seguida, basta percorrer este array com outro `for`, onde cada elemento é um `int`.

---

Esta sintaxe tem uma limitação, que é não ter acesso aos índices. Então você não conseguiria usá-la para preencher os valores da matriz. Ou seja, o código abaixo não funciona:

```
for (int[] linha : matriz) {
    for (int valor : linha) {
        valor = 1; // NÃO FUNCIONA, o valor da matriz não é alterado
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, o único jeito é fazer um `for` tradicional, conforme a [resposta do Daniel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/415836/112052). Mas se você só quer acessar os valores, sem precisar do índice, o *enhanced for* é uma alternativa.

---

Outra alternativa para somar os valores, caso esteja usando Java >= 8, é usar [*streams*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
int soma = Arrays.stream(matriz).flatMapToInt(linha -> Arrays.stream(linha)).sum();
```

[`Arrays.stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) converte a `matriz` para um *stream* de `int[]`, e [`flatMapToInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) converte cada linha da matriz (ou seja, cada `int[]`) para um [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html). O resultado é um `IntStream` contendo todos os números da matriz.

Por fim, o [método `sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) retorna a soma de todos os números.

Vale lembrar que nesse caso, talvez seja exagero usar *streams*, pois elas [têm o seu custo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670380) e [são mais lentas que um *loop* tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052).