# Java 8 stream - melhora de performance

Tags: java, lista, desempenho, java-8, stream

Estou implementado um método que recebe um valor inteiro `k` (que representa a quantidade de "vagas") e duas listas (`p` e `q`) de `Integer` e efetua algumas operações.

Utilizando *stream*, verifico quais elementos da lista `p` possuem valor >= que os valores da lista `q`. Caso exista, preciso armazenar a posição (índice + 1) de cada item numa outra lista. Contudo esta terceira lista só pode ter uma quantidade de elementos <= o valor `k` passado por parâmetro.

O código implementado encontra-se abaixo, contudo preciso melhorar o desempenho dele (acredito que os 2 `forEach` existentes estão piorando o desempenho).

```
public static List<Integer> kthPerson(int k, List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {

        List<Integer> busList = new ArrayList<>();

        q.stream().forEach(time -> {
            List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

            IntStream.range(0, p.size()).filter(i -> (p.get(i) >= time && lista.size() < k)).forEach(i -> lista.add(i+1) );
            int size = lista.size();
            if(size < k){
               busList.add(0);
            }else{
                if (lista != null && !lista.isEmpty()) {
                    busList.add(lista.get(size - 1));
                }
            }
        });
        return busList;

    }

}
```

Comment: @MarcosAntônio eu vi sua questão e as respostas. Obrigado por recomendar o link. Como você fez para remover os casos repetidos? Você implementou utilizando for aninhados ou usou stream?

Answer (score 3):

Dada a sua descrição, acho que seu código não está certo:

> *verifico quais elementos da lista `p` possuem valor >= que os valores da lista `q`. Caso exista, preciso armazenar a posição (índice + 1) de cada item numa outra lista. Contudo esta terceira lista só pode ter uma quantidade de elementos <= o valor `k`*

Testei o seu código com as listas abaixo:

```
List<Integer> p = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90);
List<Integer> q = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
System.out.println(kthPerson(3, p, q));
```

E o resultado foi:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Só que a posição 3 (que corresponde ao índice 2) de `p` é o número 30, que não é maior que os valores de `q` (já que `q` possui os valores 40 e 50, que são maiores que 30). Além disso, o resultado tem 5 elementos, que é maior que `k`.

Enfim, não ficou muito claro o que é para fazer. Eu entendi de duas maneiras:

1. verificar os elementos de `p` que são maiores que todos os elementos de `q`
2. verificar os elementos de `p` que são maiores que o elemento de `q` que está na mesma posição

Veremos soluções para cada caso.

---

## Opção 1

Se a ideia é verificar os elementos de `p` que são maiores que todos os elementos de `q`, então não precisa percorrer `q` várias vezes. Basta achar o maior elemento de `q` e verificar quais elementos de `p` são maiores ou iguais a ele. Depois basta pegar os primeiros `k` elementos e retornar a lista:

```
public static List<Integer> kthPersonOpcao1Stream(int k, List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {
    // encontrar o maior elemento de q
    int maxQ = Collections.max(q);
    return IntStream
        // iterar pelos índices de p
        .range(0, p.size())
        // pegar os elementos maiores ou iguais a maxQ
        .filter(i -> p.get(i) >= maxQ)
        // pegar somente os k primeiros
        .limit(k)
        // somar 1 ao índice
        .map(i -> i + 1)
        // converter os valores int para Integer
        .boxed()
        // coletar os valores em uma List
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Mas se a preocupação é desempenho, talvez você não devesse usar *streams*, já que [elas são mais lentas que um *loop* tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052). Claro que para poucas listas pequenas não fará tanta diferença assim, mas de qualquer forma, a solução sem *stream* seria bem simples:

```
public static List<Integer> kthPersonOpcao1Loop(int k, List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {
    int maxQ = Collections.max(q);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size() && result.size() < k; i++) {
        if (p.get(i) >= maxQ) {
            result.add(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Repare na condição do `for` (`i < p.size() && result.size() < k`), que verifica se eu já comparei todos os elementos de `p` e se a lista de resultados tem `k` elementos. Assim ele já cobre também os casos em que são encontrados menos que `k` elementos (pois `k` é o tamanho máximo que a lista de resultados pode ter, mas nada garante que sempre encontrará `k` elementos).

---

## Opção 2

Se a ideia é comparar cada elemento de `p` com o elemento de `q` que está na mesma posição, primeiro precisamos saber qual das listas é menor (por exemplo, se `p` tiver 10 elementos e `q` tiver 4, eu não preciso verificar os 10 elementos de `p`, basta verificar os 4 primeiros).

O código é bem similar à opção 1, a diferença é que em vez de comparar os elementos de `p` com o maior elemento de `q`, eu comparo apenas com os que estão na mesma posição:

```
// com stream
public static List<Integer> kthPersonOpcao2Stream(int k, List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {
    // só preciso iterar até o tamanho da menor das listas
    int size = Math.min(p.size(), q.size());
    return IntStream
        // iterar pelos índices até "size"
        .range(0, size)
        // pegar os elementos de p maiores ou iguais ao elemento de q na mesma posição
        .filter(i -> p.get(i) >= q.get(i))
        // pegar somente os k primeiros
        .limit(k)
        // somar 1 ao índice
        .map(i -> i + 1)
        // converter os valores int para Integer
        .boxed()
        // coletar os valores em uma List
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// sem stream
public static List<Integer> kthPersonOpcao2Loop(int k, List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {
    int size = Math.min(p.size(), q.size());
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size && result.size() < k; i++) {
        if (p.get(i) >= q.get(i)) {
            result.add(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta.

Comment: @Yan Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma boa solução para esse problema nessa pargunta [How to find all K-th elements for each expiration time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965698/how-to-find-all-k-th-elements-for-each-expiration-time), o melhor tempo obtido foi utilizando Arrays ao invés de List/Streams. Caso o problema te forneça os dados em List é só fazer um parse para Array e no final realiza outro parse de volta para List, só dessa forma consegui passar em todos os caso de teste.

```java
public static int[] kth(int k, int[] t, int[] e) {
        int[] kth = new int[e.length];

        if (k > t.length)
            return kth;

        Arrays.sort(e);
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {            
            for (int j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
                if (t[j] >= e[i])
                    c++;

                if (c >= k) {
                    kth[i] = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (c < k)
                break;

            c = 0;
        }

        return kth;
}
```

Comment: @MarcosAntônio eu vi sua questão e as respostas. Obrigado por recomendar o link. Como você fez para remover os casos repetidos? Você implementou utilizando for aninhados ou usou stream?

Comment: @Yan eu removi os elementos repetidos usando Stream e no final criei o array List com todos os elementos