# Buscar string dentro de lista Java

Tags: java

Tenho um array com informações de vários filmes, e preciso buscar o nome dos filmes independente de ele estar UpperCase ou LowerCase, e preciso que por exemplo, ao buscar o nome "para" ele me retorne todos os filmes que tenham "para" no nome, independente de estar no inicio ou no final. Eu encontrei duas formas:

```
if (filmes.getNomeFilme().contains(name)) {
```

Dessa forma ele me retorna os filmes mas não ignora o case sensitive

Essa outra forma aqui:

```
if (filmes.getNomeFilme().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
```

Dessa forma ele ignora o case sensitive mas o usuário tem que passar o nome completo do filme para ele encontrar.

Comment: basta converter pra lowerCase para comparar: `filmes.getNomeFilme().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase());`

Comment: Valeu ai pessoal, deu certo a resposta do Ricardo, agora está tudo funcionando certinho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode usar a api de stream para trabalhar seus dados, dessa forma por exemplo:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Nomes{
        public static void main(String args[]){
                String[] nomes = {"lara","LAURA","MaUra","Bruna"};
                
                Stream.of(nomes).map(f -> f.toLowerCase()).filter(f -> f.contains("a")).forEach(System.out::println);           
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
                Stream.of(nomes).map(f -> f.toLowerCase()).filter(f -> f.contains("au")).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
}
```

Ele vai passar todos para letra minuscula e depois filtrar por igual, pelo parametro passado

Answer (score 0):

A princípio, basta transformar tudo em minúsculas:

```
if (filmes.getNomeFilme().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase()))
```

Ou em maiúsculas:

```
if (filmes.getNomeFilme().toUpperCase().contains(name.toUpperCase()))
```

Só vale lembrar que existe a ineficiência de ficar criando novas strings toda hora (cada chamada de `toUpperCase` e `toLowerCase` retorna outra string modificada).

<sup>Sem contar alguns casos "estranhos" dependendo do idioma (detalhados [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966206)). Mas se só tiver textos em português, esses problemas não ocorrem, então fica o link como referência.</sup>

---

Uma outra alternativa é usar [`regionMatches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches-boolean-int-java.lang.String-int-int-), que apesar de não ser tão direto, é mais eficiente (código baseado [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25379180)):

```
public static boolean containsIgnoreCase(String src, String what) {
    final int length = what.length();
    if (length == 0)
        return true; // string vazia retorna true

    final char firstLo = Character.toLowerCase(what.charAt(0));
    final char firstUp = Character.toUpperCase(what.charAt(0));

    for (int i = src.length() - length; i >= 0; i--) {
        // verifica só pra ter certeza antes de chamar regionMatches sem necessidade
        final char ch = src.charAt(i);
        if (ch != firstLo && ch != firstUp)
            continue;

        if (src.regionMatches(true, i, what, 0, length))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

E aí bastaria fazer:

```
if (containsIgnoreCase(filmes.getNomeFilme(), name))
```

---

Só por curiosidade, fiz um pequeno teste com o [JMH (Java Microbenchmark Harness)](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), e o resultado foi:

```
Benchmark                                         Mode  Samples        Score  Score error  Units
o.s.StringContainsBenchmark.testLowerCase        thrpt      200  5983873,852    79952,187  ops/s
o.s.StringContainsBenchmark.testRegionMatches    thrpt      200  7047000,300   199599,775  ops/s
```

No caso, a solução com `regionMatches` teve mais de 7 milhões de operações por segundo, contra 5.9 milhões da solução com `toLowerCase`.

Lembrando, é claro, que isso pode variar conforme o *hardware* e os dados sendo testados. Mas de forma geral, `regionMatches` se saiu melhor que `toLowerCase`.

Código do teste:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Setup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class StringContainsBenchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(StringContainsBenchmark.class.getSimpleName()).warmupIterations(5).measurementIterations(5).forks(3).build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    List<String> nomes;
    String busca;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        nomes = Arrays.asList("Fulano de tal", "ciclano de qual", "beltrano da SILVA", "Trajano de sOUZa");
        busca = "ano";
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testRegionMatches(Blackhole bh) {
        for (String s : nomes) {
            bh.consume(comRegionMatches(s, busca));
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void testLowerCase(Blackhole bh) {
        for (String s : nomes) {
            bh.consume(comLowerCase(s, busca));
        }
    }

    private boolean comRegionMatches(String src, String busca) {
        final int length = busca.length();
        if (length == 0)
            return true; // string vazia retorna true

        final char firstLo = Character.toLowerCase(busca.charAt(0));
        final char firstUp = Character.toUpperCase(busca.charAt(0));

        for (int i = src.length() - length; i >= 0; i--) {
            // verifica só pra ter certeza antes de chamar regionMatches sem necessidade
            final char ch = src.charAt(i);
            if (ch != firstLo && ch != firstUp)
                continue;

            if (src.regionMatches(true, i, busca, 0, length))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean comLowerCase(String src, String busca) {
        return src.toLowerCase().contains(busca.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

---

A outra resposta usou *streams* para iterar pelas strings, que também funciona, mas eu acho um exagero para um caso em que um *loop* simples com `if` resolve.

Apesar de "legais", *streams* [têm seu custo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670380) e por isso [são mais lentas que um *loop* "tradicional"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052). Não que seja errado usar, desde que esteja ciente das implicações.