# Obter todos os elementos de uma lista cujo valor seja igual ao maior

Tags: java, lista, stream

Tenho uma lista:

```java
// pseudo-código
List<Object> abc = Arrays.asList({id: 7}, {id: 3}, {id: 7}, {id: 1}, {id: 4}, {id: 7}, {id: 7});
```

E quero pegar via *stream* apenas os objetos com o maior valor de id, ou seja, quero como resultado:

```java
// pseudo-código
List<Object> abc = Arrays.asList({id: 7}, {id: 7}, {id: 7}, {id: 7});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que o objeto seja algo assim:

```java
public class MyObject {
    private int id;
    public MyObject(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Basta você agrupar os elementos de acordo com o id, ou seja, crie um `Map` que mapeia cada id para uma lista contendo os elementos que possuem aquele id.
Depois, basta pegar a lista correspondente ao maior id:

```java
List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(new MyObject(7), new MyObject(3), new MyObject(7), new MyObject(1), new MyObject(4), new MyObject(7), new MyObject(7));
List<MyObject> objetosComMaiorId = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getId, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .lastEntry()
        .getValue();
System.out.println(objetosComMaiorId);
```

O método `collect` recebe um *collector*, que no caso é criado por `groupingBy`: é ele que faz o mapeamento de cada id para uma lista contendo os elementos que possuem aquele id.

E para fazer o mapeamento eu uso um `TreeMap`, que ordena as chaves automaticamente. E como as chaves são os id's, basta pegar o último (`lastEntry`) para ter a lista que corresponde ao maior id.

---

Claro que você também pode percorrer a lista duas vezes: uma para ver qual é o maior id, e outra para filtrar os elementos que possuem tal id:

```java
int maiorId = list.stream()
        .mapToInt(MyObject::getId)
        .max()
        .orElse(-1);
List<MyObject> objetosComMaiorId = list.stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getId() == maiorId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Esta solução percorre a lista duas vezes e só cria a sub-lista referente ao maior id, já a solução com `TreeMap` percorre a lista apenas uma vez, porém gera as sub-listas para todos os id's. É o velho e conhecido [*space-time tradeoff*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff).

---

#### Sem *stream*

Só para constar, [*streams* geralmente são mais lentas que um *loop* simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361956/112052), e daria para resolver sem elas.

Seja usando o `Map` (e daria para obter o maior valor separadamente, aí nem precisaria usar `TreeMap`):

```java
int maiorId = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Map<Integer, List<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (MyObject obj : list) {
    int id = obj.getId();
    if (id > maiorId) {
        maiorId = id;
    }
    if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
        map.put(id, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(id).add(obj);
}
List<MyObject> objetosComMaiorId = map.get(maiorId);
```

Ou percorrendo a lista duas vezes (uma para achar o maior id, outra para filtrar os elementos com este id):

```java
int maiorId = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (MyObject obj : list) {
    if (obj.getId() > maiorId) {
        maiorId = obj.getId();
    }
}
List<MyObject> objetosComMaiorId = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyObject obj : list) {
    if (obj.getId() == maiorId) {
        objetosComMaiorId.add(obj);
    }
}
```