# Imprimir intervalos de números com final 5

Tags: java, algoritmo, matemática

Estou tentando imprimir os números de 0 a 200 que possuem apenas o número 5 como último algarismo.

```
package Exercícios;

public class NumerosQueComeçamComAlgarimo5 {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não bastaria iniciar seu contador com 5 e incrementar de 10 em 10? `int i = 5; i <= 200; i += 10`

Comment: Um caso claro de "primeiro resolva o problema, depois escreva o código". Como você pretende verificar se o último algarismo é 5?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu queria entender o "apenas", pq no "possuem apenas o número 5 como último algarismo" sugere que possa ter mais de um último?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

É extremamente simples e eficiente porque a linguagem tem tudo o que precisa para fazer isto matematicamente. Não é nem questão de programação e sim solução de problema matemático.

Se você deseja que sempre mostre números com final 5 concorda que deve começar pelo 5?. E se quiser manter a distância entre eles sempre igual e mantendo o final 5 então temos uma dezena de diferença, portanto devemos incrementar o número de 10 em 10, então é só isto:

```
public class NumerosQueComeçamComAlgarimo5 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (int i = 5; i <= 200; i+= 10) System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Kv5o9c). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/tpuqslro-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/Increment.java).

Por favor não use qualquer solução que não seja pura matemática, e simples, não faz sentido fazer de outra forma mais complicada.

Mantive o título da classe, mas ele parece errado, ou o enunciado do problema está errado. Se o problema for o que diz o título, aí o algoritmo é um pouco mais complexo, mas dá para fazer matematicamente ainda.

Por alguma razão a pergunta atraiu diversidade de soluções. Isso costuma ser bom, a não ser quando cada uma é mais convoluta que outra. Teve uma apagada que trabalhava com *strings* que era bem complicada, outras existem com uma lógica complicada que não acrescentava nada, só piorava. Tem uma resposta que dá uma vantagem que a pergunta não pede, mas poderia fazer sentido para outras pessoa. Pode ser que a pessoa não tenha os parâmetros fixos. O problema da resposta é que ela ficou complicada demais e por incrível que pareça [abstrata de menos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360556/101). Claramente a resposta tentou abstrair certas partes, mas falhou em abstrair o que era o mais importante. A resposta seria boa se fizesse:

```
public class NumerosQueComeçamComAlgarimo5 {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        IncrementInterval(5, 200);
    }
    public static void IncrementInterval(int inicio, int limite) {
        for (int i = inicio; i <= limite; i+= 10) System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Se quiser pode fazer uma validação e garantir que o limite seja maior que o intervalo, ou verificar que o final seja entre 0 e 9.

Custava só colocar parâmetros no início e fim em vez de criar um `if` sem sentido e ineficiente e criar funções para esconder algo sem ganho algum. OOP está destruindo a cabeça das pessoas.

Vou aproveitar e desabafar quanto ao estado da nossa indústria. As pessoas perderam a noção do simples. Agora tudo tem que ser complicado para ser "certo". Tem que fazer TDD, DDD, xDD, microsserviços, tem que por na nuvem, em *container*, tem que ter um *build* complexo, ter N camadas, até mesmo o uso de OOP é absurdamente sobrevalorizado e abusado. E abstração também acaba criando complexidade excessiva, embora muitas vezes a falta dela é o real problema. É tão difícil fazer uma simples função e usar um laço simples demais?

Answer (score 3):

Aqui uma solução para o caso de querer verificar se um número qualquer termina em 5:

```
// só como explicação/demonstração, num caso real 
// se usa essa expressão diretamente
int digitoFinal(int numero) {
    return Math.abs(numero) % 10;
}

// vide comentário anterior
boolean terminaEmCinco(int numero) {
    return digitoFinal(numero) == 5;
}

// aqui num laço, novamente só como demonstrração
// ver resposta do Maniero 
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if (terminaEmCinco(i)) {  // ou if ((i % 10) == 5) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Essa solução é apenas para demonstrar uma possibilidade para o caso de não se ter um *loop*, mas, por exemplo, um valor retornado de uma função qualquer.
Basicamente usa o fato que módulo 10 (`% 10`) aplicado a um número resulta no último dígito desse número.

A resposta do Maniero é a mais adequada e eficiente para o caso de se ter valores fixos (como requerido na pergunta).

Comment: Eu não acredito o que aconteceu nessa pergunta, virou competição de quem dá a resposta mais rebuscada. Me desculpem o desabafo, mas é inacreditável o estado que as coisas chegaram. Ninguém mais quer solução simples. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png

Comment: Eu acho que não ficou _enterprise_ o suficiente, precisava ser `terminaEmValor(int numeroA, int numeroB) {` `digitoFinal(numeroA) == numeroB` :)

Comment: @Bacco mas eu acho que precisava criar uma classe e usar o estado compartilhado entre os métodos, aí fica mais na moda.

Comment: Eu não quis ser muito exigente, por isso nem sugeri fazer uma classe de testes e um TDD.

Comment: A única solução inteligente que é diferente que vi até agora foi dada em chat pelo Anderson Carlos Woss: `System.out.println("5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95, 105, 115, 125, 135, 145, 155, 165, 175, 185, 195");`, mas claro que ela é sacanagem porque não pode ser variável e provavelmente vai contra o exercício que é fazer um laço, mas seria a mais simples, apesar de mais verbosa.

Comment: @Bacco DDD também, algum DP

Comment: A solução já foi apresentada no início do tópico alterando o contador, sei que foi uma pergunta simples, mas não deixa de ser uma dúvida. Sou iniciante no ramo da programação e agradeço os membros da comunidade pela colaboração, pois os mesmos possuem um vasto conhecimento. Porém é desnecessário ficarem discutindo por uma dúvida já resolvida.

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que entendi você quer imprimir os números que têm o seu ultimo algarismo terminado em 5 (isso é o que diz na sua pergunta), ou seja : 5, 15, 25, 35 etc. Uma outra forma de resolver isto, além dessas que os colegas mencionaram acima, seria verificando se o número é par, pois se você for pulando de 5 em 5, será 5(ímpar), 10(par), 15(ímpar), 20(par)... então toda vez que você tiver um numero ímpar ele será terminado em 5, no código isso ficaria assim:

```
public class numerosTerminadosEmCinco {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 5; i <= 200; i += 10) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Pra que fazer isto? Que benefício há em fazer um `if` desnecessário? Se tirá-lo dá exatamente o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Se você inicia em 5 e incrementa 10, você **nunca** terá um valor par - aliás, não há como um número terminado em 5 ser par, então a sua condição será sempre verdadeira. Para provar isso, basta fazer 5 + 10*k, sendo k inteiro, que pode ser reescrito como 5*(2k+1); para que este valor seja múltiplo de 2 o fator (2k+1) precisa ser par. Não existe valor de k inteiro que faça esse valor ser par.

Answer (score -2):

A resposta do Maniero está perfeita.

Só gostaria de adicionar uma opção caso tu não queira alterar o teu loop, ou seja, iterando todos os números de 0 a 200.

Uma maneira de determinar se o útimo número é igual a 5, seria usando o operador resto "%".

Primeiro: todo número que for divisível por cinco, termina em 5 ou 0. Ex: 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc. Então se tu usar o operador resto fazendo a divisão por cinco, somente irá te retornar os números que terminarem em cinco e em zero.

Segundo: para determinar se o número termina em 5 ou em 0, use o operador resto dividindo por 2. Nesse caso, somente retornará resto se o número terminar em 5.

Ex:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
        if((i % 5) == 0) {
            if((i % 2) != 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho isto tão desnecessário. Não sei porque as pessoas estão pegando uma solução simples e criando uma solução ineficiente e que não ajudam em nada. Dar soluções criativas não tem valor se elas são piores que a já oferecida. Existem casos que a solução pode ser uma alternativa, mas só porque é diferente e que funcione não quer dizer que é uma boa solução. Criar 4 linhas de código, 2 *branchs* que aumenta a complexidade ciclomática e novas instruções de execução que são bem caras não é algo bom, só piora a legibilidade pra ganho zero.

Comment: vc nao precisa de 2 if so precisa colocar na mesma linha `if((i % 5) == 0 && (i % 2) != 0)`

Comment: Tudo começa levantando os requisitos. Já tive que responder a um exercício em que o loop era dado e não podia ser alterado, somente poderia ser adicionado código ao corpo do loop, por isso ofereci esta solução. Se a não alteração do loop for um requisito do exercício, a solução proposta não resolve.