# Lista como entrada de funções

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, lista, argumento

Em Python 3.7 itens de uma lista podem ser argumentos de uma função?

```
def media(x,y,z):  lista = [7,8,9]
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual significado do operador ( \* ) asterisco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162956/qual-significado-do-operador-asterisco)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, este código não parece fazer muito sentido, mas imagino que seja isto que deseja:

```
def media(x, y, z):
    return (x + y + z) // 3 
lista = [7, 8, 9]
media(*lista)
```

Note que este exemplo em específico não faz tanto sentido, o ideal em caso de média já é receber uma lista mesmo e não um número limitado de argumentos. Isto daria erro:

```
print(media(*[8, 9]))
print(media(*[6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Isto parece mais com o que deseja:

```
def media(*lista):
    soma = 0
    for i in lista:
        soma += i
    return soma // len(lista)
lista = [7, 8, 9]
print(media(*lista))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/toQjao). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vvirejzj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/AverageList.py).

Comment: Muito obrigado!. Faz parte de um exercício que estou praticando. Coloquei apenas um pedaço, o qual me tirou o sono, para seguir com os demais.

Comment: No código apresentado da função media o uso o * para o parâmetro lista pode ser omitido. Caso feito isso, na última linha, quando é feito a impressão da média, não se deve usar o * também.

Comment: @Pa me parece não ser verdade, eu teste e deu erro.