# Como realizar uma subtração de diversos elementos de uma lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Eu estou fazendo uma calculadora e gostaria de realizar a subtração de vários elementos de uma lista, isso pois a lista pode ter quantos elementos o usuário desejar. Veja meu código:

```
lista = [10, 5]
subt = lista[0]
for a in lista:
  subt -= a
```

Porém o algoritmo está me dando -5 como resposta, sendo que deveria ser 5 (10-5 = 5). Vale ressaltar novamente que a lista pode ter quantos elementos o usuário quiser, seja 2, 3, 4, 5, 100...

Qual uma possível solução?

Comment: para uma lista assim 2, 3, 4, 5, 100 o que vc espera como resultado ??

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você quer subtrair o primeiro elemento dos demais, uma alternativa é fazer o *loop* a partir do segundo elemento:

```
subt = lista[0]
for a in lista[1:]:
    subt -= a
```

No caso, `lista[1:]` cria uma sub-lista contendo do segundo elemento em diante (`[1:]` usa a sintaxe de [*slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para pegar do índice 1 até o final da lista - caso a lista tenha somente um elemento, a sub-lista será vazia e não entrará no `for`).

Isso segue a mesma ideia da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/451526/112052), só estou criando a sub-lista de uma maneira diferente.

---

Outro modo de enxergar o problema é perceber que na verdade você quer fazer:

```
primeiro_elemento - soma_dos_demais_elementos
```

Traduzindo para Python, ficaria assim:

```
subt = lista[0] - sum(lista[1:])
```

Answer (score 5):

Você está pegando a lista toda, então a primeira subtração é o elemento que já havia pego antes, o primeiro passo do laço zerará o valor porque um número menos ele menos sempre é zero, aí começa a conta.

A solução é pegar o primeiro item ali e depois trabalhar só com o resto da lista. Python tem uma forma para fazer isso de forma simples. Você pode usar a habilidade de decompor vários valores em variáveis, então você terá o primeiro elemento em uma variável e depois para colocar todos os elementos restantes usará o operador `*` (caso contrário pegaria só o segundo valor, o que até funciona nesse exemplo, mas não funcionaria em listas maiores). Algo assim:

```
subt, *tail = [10, 5]
for a in tail:
    subt -= a
print(subt)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Awqmhn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xudyhefi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/HeadTail.py).

Veja mais em [Qual significado do operador ( * ) asterisco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162956/101) e [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).