# Subtração em Python

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer a subtração simples de uma lista.

```
#02.1 - inserir a quantidade de números a serem calculados

sub_val = int(input("Digite a quantidade de valores: "))
qtd_val = 0

# nesta etapa, pegar a quantidade informada, 
for i in range (0, sub_val):

# criar a lista com valores e a seguir realizar a subtração
    qtd_val = int(input("Digite o valor " +str(i + 1)+": ")) - qtd_val

# aqui mostra o resultado
    print(qtd_val)
```

Ele até calcula, mas deixa números em negativo, ou não faz como deveria fazer em uma calculadora simples. Como posso corrigir?

não sei como organizar os valores para que ele faça como uma calculadora faria tipo 33 - 44 - 55 = -66. atualmente esta formula responde 44.

e também preciso aprender a usar valores em lista.
Vou aprender as regras de postagem também, agradeço todo o apoio.

Comment: Não entendi o objetivo, você quer armazenar os valores em uma lista e depois fazer a subtração entre eles?

Comment: Ao meu ver ele executou corretamente. Igual a uma calculadora. A questão principal é a ordem que você colocar os números. Ex. Faça ai na sua calculadora mesmo 9-5 e 5-9, vão dar valores diferentes. Então no seu também está correto, dependendo da ordem que você inserir os valores para subtração.

Comment: @LucasSousaAlves a intenção é saber quantos numeros quer realizar a subtração, tipo informo 03, ai ele questona quais são estes 3 numeros. e por fim faz a subtração.

Comment: @EduardoGarciadeOliveira então agora me resta aprender pois não sei como organizar os valores para que ele faça como uma calculadora faria tipo 33 - 44 - 55 = -66. atualmente esta formula responde 44.

Comment: @RafaelGuindani Por favor clique em [edit] e coloque essas informações na pergunta, assim quem for tentar responder não precisa ficar "caçando" informações nos comentários. Mas de forma resumida, se é para fazer a conta desta forma, então o primeiro número não pode ser subtraído. Também sugiro fazer um [teste de mesa](/q/220474/112052) para entender o que o código faz (assim entenderá melhor porque ele não funciona) - outra forma de resolver seria guardar os números em uma lista e fazer [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451521/112052) (se bem que não precisaria, dá pra resolver sem lista)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um teste de mesa para entender o que está acontecendo no seu código.
Vou te dar um exemplo para essas 3 entradas: 33; 44; 55;

```
i = 0:
qtd_val = 0; 
entrada = 33;
qtd_val = 33 - 0 = 33

i = 1:
qtd_val = 33;
entrada = 44;
qtd_val = 44 - 33 = 11

i = 2:
qtd_val = 11;
entrada = 55;
qtd_val = 55 - 11 = 44
```

Uma forma de fazer a operação que você quer, aproveitando seu código, seria

```
    sub_val = int(input("Digite a quantidade de valores: "))
    qtd_val = 0
    
    #pegar o valor inicial que será subtraído
    qtd_val = int(input("Digite o valor inicial" +str(i + 1)+": "))

    # nesta etapa, pegar os valores que subtrairão, 
    for i in range (0, sub_val-1):
        
    # ler os valores e realizar a subtração
        qtd_val -= int(input("Digite o valor para subtrair" +str(i + 1)+": "))
```

lembre-se de verificar se sub_val >0

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).